# Ruby on Rails: Extract SQL returns error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, postgresql

I'm working a sale management database.

To calculate a sale summary for each month, I wrote controller method, the method is triggered by an HTML POST request.

The way it works is to separate orders into groups of different months. First is to check if the year already exists in the database then the month. If that month already existed in the Data table, update its attributes , if not create a new data object with the new month.

Calculate the total_cost, revenue for each month.

Then the record will be saved into my database.

```
def generate_report
  @orders_by_month = current_user.orders.all.group_by { |order| order.order_date.beginning_of_month }

  @orders_by_month.each do |month, orders|
    if current_user.data.where("extract(year from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%Y').to_i).present?
      this_year = current_user.data.where("extract(year from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%Y').to_i)
      if this_year.where("extract(month from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%m').to_i).present?
        @report = this_year.where("extract(month from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%m').to_i).first
      end
    else
      @report = Datum.new
    end
    vnd = orders.first.vnd.to_f
    total_cost = (orders.map(&:total_cost).sum.to_f / vnd).round(2)
    selling = (orders.map(&:selling_price).sum.to_f / vnd).round(2)
    count = orders.count

    @report.month_record = month
    @report.total_cost = total_cost
    @report.total_selling = selling
    @report.revenue = (selling - total_cost).round(2)
    @report.order_sold = count
    @report.user_id = current_user.id

    @report.save

    orders.each do |order|
      order.update_attributes(datum_id: @report.id)
    end
end

    redirect_to user_report_path(current_user)
end
```

end

There's no problem with routing. Both my development and production(Heroku) are using Postgresql

This is my gem file if you are interested:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
#gem 'pjax_rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'

gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'

gem 'goog_currency'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'public_activity'
gem 'pg'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Note that everything ran just fine in my development. However, I got this error from heroku logs:

```
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-07-23T05:02:39.250745+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/1/report" for 123.16.255.248 at 2015-07-23 05:02:39 +0000
2015-07-23T05:02:39.268004+00:00 app[web.1]:   Datum Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "data".* FROM "data" WHERE "data"."user_id" = $1 AND (extract(year from month_record) = 2015)  [["user_id", 1]]
2015-07-23T05:02:39.270829+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms
2015-07-23T05:02:39.252943+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"pB0Aqc9oRumYxCgoIzeoGEDJqsyQLRiUCYI7QTHVCmuBfPpaSdXmuHUO6oauTzIi2SsbrB5zhUywSGgw5YPNhw==", "user_id"=>"1"}
2015-07-23T05:02:39.254935+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2015-07-23T05:02:39.260848+00:00 app[web.1]:   Order Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2015-07-23T05:02:39.269970+00:00 app[web.1]:   Datum Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "data".* FROM "data" WHERE "data"."user_id" = $1 AND (extract(year from month_record) = 2015) AND (extract(month from month_record) = 6)  [["user_id", 1]]
2015-07-23T05:02:39.271916+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `month_record=' for nil:NilClass):
2015-07-23T05:02:39.252920+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ReportsController#generate_report as HTML
2015-07-23T05:02:39.271914+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-23T05:02:39.271918+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:31:in `block in generate_report'
2015-07-23T05:02:39.271921+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:17:in `generate_report'
2015-07-23T05:02:39.271920+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:17:in `each'
2015-07-23T05:02:39.271923+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-23T05:02:39.271924+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-23T05:02:39.273133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/1/report" host=red-moose-2689.herokuapp.com request_id=d4cdd0fa-739d-48f9-87ce-eae4a597
```

Compare to the development.log:

```
Started POST "/users/1/report" for ::1 at 2015-07-23 11:19:04 +0700
Processing by ReportsController#generate_report as HTML
Parameters:         {"authenticity_token"=>"WFrVOTwDrTg7sZLhz+RkLOeKUYXixjddEDuhkUrzxWYerG9F9KPz3DWNTagbhbAMPLU0xpQNd805UDIjO3w+uA==", "user_id"=>"1"}
[1m[35mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
[1m[35mOrder Load (1.5ms)[0m  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
[1m[36mDatum Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "data".* FROM "data" WHERE "data"."user_id" = $1 AND (extract(year from month_record) = 2016)[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
[1m[35mDatum Load (0.8ms)[0m  SELECT "data".* FROM "data" WHERE "data"."user_id" = $1 AND (extract(year from month_record) = 2016) AND (extract(month from month_record) = 7)  [["user_id", 1]]
[1m[36mDatum Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "data".* FROM "data" WHERE "data"."user_id" = $1 AND (extract(year from month_record) = 2016) AND (extract(month from month_record) = 7)  ORDER BY "data"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
[1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
[1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "data" SET "revenue" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "data"."id" = $3[0m  [["revenue", "-525.710000000000036379788070917129516602"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-23 04:19:04.938382"], ["id", 5]]
[1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
```

Sorry, for my bad English. I hope you can understand my problem. I reached the dead end here. I appreciate any help.

**Update:**

Github repo for this project: https://github.com/LongPotato/Gotato

`reports_controllers.rb`

An error occur when lookup existed `month` under nested `if` conditions, some how it bypassed the check condition and return `nil` object to `@report`.

Comment: Possibly this line is giving you `nil` value: `@report = this_year.where("extract(month from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%m').to_i).first` which means there is no record in db.

Comment: I know, but it works perfectly fine on my localhost server. You can see it by comparing the 2 logs

Comment: Yes so this has no connection with your code. You have no data corresponding to your query on server whereas your local database has that.

Comment: Can you explain to me in the Heroku logs, after "Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms" why does the server keep running until the NoMethodError ?. I'm new to ruby on rails, thank you

Comment: Actually as I said above `@report` is `nil` and in further statements it is trying to do `nil.month_record` which is not a valid operation so it is throwing error.

Comment: Thank you. I am very confused because, both of my development and production databases are seeded from the same `seeds.rb` file. I don't know why it's return `nil`. I will take a look and make sure that my heroku database are fine.

Comment: @Deep, for the `nil` return value problem as you said above. I already had this check: `if this_year.where("extract(month from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%m').to_i).present?`. How come it still return `nil` if not `present`. Is `present?` check good enough?

Comment: if you check it you will find in the if condtion it is `.strftime('%Y')` and when fetching the value it is `.strftime('%m')`

Comment: I will explain my code a little bit. In `@orders_by_month.each` loop, For example, this is the return for `month`: `Fri, 01 Jul 2016`. First, I check if the year already existed in the data base, as you can see in `.strftime('%Y')` if clause. Then if that year exist, I check if that specific month of that year exists, `.strftime('%m')` if clause. Else I proceed to create new data object. I updated my post with my github repo. If you are interested, please take a look and help me out :). Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed Problem:**

Add an `else` clause after the second `if` to prevent assigning `nil` to `@report`

```
def generate_report
@orders_by_month = current_user.orders.all.group_by { |order| order.order_date.beginning_of_month }

  @orders_by_month.each do |month, orders|
  if current_user.data.where("extract(year from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%Y').to_i).present?
    this_year = current_user.data.where("extract(year from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%Y').to_i)
    if this_year.where("extract(month from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%m').to_i).present?
      @report = this_year.where("extract(month from month_record) = ?", month.strftime('%m').to_i).first
    else
      @report = Datum.new
    end
  else
    @report = Datum.new
  end
  vnd = orders.first.vnd.to_f
  total_cost = (orders.map(&:total_cost).sum.to_f / vnd).round(2)
 .
 .
 .
end
end
```